# Cursor is not loading correctly to listview?

Tags: android, listview

I am doing simple listview.I want to load contacts names and When I click listview"s item ,I want to setBackgroundcolor blue.But I have 3 problems.First of all my cursor don"t load to listview correctly.It is repeating yourself. Second problem is; When I click any item in listview,My listview is painting more than 1 items.Third one is :When I click last items,My program get exception.How can I load names to listview always correctly?How can I fix it ?`

```
public class display extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv ;
    Button select;
    String phoneNumber;

    ArrayList <String> aa= new ArrayList<String>();





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
        select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getNumber(this.getContentResolver());}

    public void getNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
        Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber);
            aa.add(name);
        }
        phones.close();// close cursor
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,aa);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
    }

}
```

My layout file :

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_above="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Select" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one.

```
public class display extends AppCompatActivity {
  ListView lv ;
  Button your_button; // don't use java data type "select"
  String name, phoneNumber;

  ArrayList<String> aa;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    your_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    aa= new ArrayList<String>();
    getNumber(this.getContentResolver());
  }

  public void getNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    if (phones.getCount() != 0) {
      if (phones.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
          name= phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
          phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
          aa.add(name + "\n" + phoneNumber);
        } while (phones.moveToNext());
        phones.close();// close cursor
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, aa);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
      }      
    }
  }
}
```